# What's wrong with the following arithmetic operation? C++

Tags: c++, codeblocks, long-integer, division

I'm just trying to do a simple arithmetic operation but it returns me the 0 value. Here's the code:

```
 main(){

 long Population_A, Population_B; 

 cin>>Population_A;
 cin>>Population_B;

 float Increase_A, Increase_B;

 Increase_A = (6*Population_A)/100; //Here is the problem because I receive 0.
 Increase_B = (3*Population_B)/100;

 }//main
```

Comment: Is Population_A greater than 16?

Comment: You've posted code that won't compile, that even if it did compile wouldn't actually show any problem, and even if it could show any problem, you haven't provided the input your program needs to show that problem.

Comment: integer division has already been addressed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c

Comment: @CarlNorum I figured out the problem. But why if Population_A is less than 16 will failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Population_A` is in the range -16 .. 16, the integer multiply and divide will result in 0.

If you want floating point division results rather than converting integer values to floats, change `6` to `6.0F` and `3` to `3.0F`.

Comment: I figured out the problem. But why if Population_A is less than 16 will failed?